# Create checkbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

Below is my implementation code:-

```
 [self.tncCheckBoxLabel setTitle:@"Accept Terms and Conditions" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.tncCheckBoxLabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Unchecked Checkbox Filled-50.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.tncCheckBoxLabel setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checked Checkbox Filled-50.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

//onClick method
- (IBAction)tncCheckBoxPressed:(id)sender {
    //self.tncCheckBoxLabel.selected = !self.tncCheckBoxLabel.selected;
    self.tncCheckBoxLabel.selected = !self.tncCheckBoxLabel.selected;
}
```

The initial view:

[image]

The view after clicking on the button:

[image]

The initial view is good but after clicking on the button, the image wrapped itself on the text.

I would like to display the checked image to the left which looks like the initial view.

Comment: Check image name is proper or not?

Comment: Check image size and try setting the text of button for selected mode separately?

Comment: Solved it by making changes on the button in Interface Builder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7136510/how-to-set-the-button-image-for-uicontrolstateselected

Comment: did you set image as button image not as background image ? @SPUDERMAN